# Как сделать на adaptive разделитель строки на html и css

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, responsive

Есть футер сайта

```css
.heart {
  color: red;
  margin: 0 12px;
}

.footer1 {
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.footer2 {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 4px;
}

.txt {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer1">
  <span class="txt">Some text 1</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 2</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 3</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 4</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 5</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 6</span>
</footer>


<footer class="footer2">
  <span class="txt">Some text 1</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 2</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 3</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 4</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 5</span>
  <span class="heart">❤</span>
  <span class="txt">Some text 6</span>
</footer>
```

Необходимо сделать так, что бы при любом размере блока внутри строки показывались только промежуточные сердечки, но не крайние.

В примере кода во втором блоке должно скрыться сердечко после 3-его текста. И в зависимости от размера скрываться лишние.

Наилучший вариант это решение на чистом css без media query.

Код разметки может быть любой, главное что бы получить необходимый результат.